# Where to add 3DS parameters in the payment request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, payment-gateway, spree

We are using `spree e-commerce` platform to build our application which in ruby on rails framework. We wanted to just implement the 3D secure payment method into the existing payment option available with us. The adyen payment gateway is already implemented in the application, just wanted to know how to achieve `3d secure payment processing`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a later response but for those who end up here this may help.
I'm currently developing an integration for Mangopay in Spree so I don't have the full answer, but in order to make 3Ds to work you'll have to make some changes:

- change the update method on checkout controller to redirect to 3ds url once the payment is created
- change the payment processing logic in spree to start_processing instead of complete the payment once you get a successful response from adyen (first stage of 3DS)
- change the adyen gateway to support 3DS (as far as I know the implementation in ActiveMerchant does not add anything for 3Ds, but I just made a quick look)
- add some route, controller and action to process the callback from 3DS and update spree payment and order acordingly

Here you can find useful information:

- [Spree Mollie Gateway Extension](https://github.com/mollie/spree-mollie-gateway) they implement Mollie Gateway with 3DS support
- [Active Merchant Gem](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant)
- [Spree Extension Tutorial](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/tutorials/extensions_tutorial.html)

Feel free to contact me if you have further questions